# An efficient algorithm for renaming

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

If I have a list of variables, [a, b, a, c, a, a, d, b, c, d, a] where order is important, 
and I have to rename them into integers, what is the best algorithm that I can use?

A trivial algorithm will be:

1. Create an empty hash table, HT.
2. For each variable in the list,

   1. If it is not indexed, assign a new index to it and put the (variable, index) in HT.
   2. If it is indexed, use the index.

In the above case, the solution will be [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1]

I am concerned with the 'n' hash lookups and the complexity that comes with this. For really long lists (with more distinct vars), the performance may be really bad. Does anyone have a better algorithm to handle this?

Note that while the example uses ascii characters, the elements of the list can be arbitrary strings, the length of the list can be arbitrarily long (> 100k), etc.

Comment: I thought hash table lookup was O(1) unless you got clashes

Comment: You mean `O(1)` hash lookup right? `O(1)` for `N` items is the efficiency of the total algorithm, not the hash lookup.

Comment: Do the numbers have to start with 1 and be sequential?  Or just distinct?

Comment: If your variable-names are all one-letter names, you can use an int[128] and use the ASCII-value of the one-letter-name-character as index. This would avoid the hash table.

Comment: In your example you could simply use the one character name of the variable and calculate the number by using `character-'a'+1` as number. This would produce `'a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2 , 'c' -> 3, 'd' -> 4`.

Comment: the numbers have to be distinct; need not be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n)` worst case hash lookup only occurs when using a naive collision resolution (and all items are mapped to the identical hash value) - you actually employ hashing because you expect collisions to be 'rare' thus benefiting on average from the `O(1)` lookup time.

as you have to check all your variables for duplicates you won't fare better than `O(n)` in total.

perhaps you can exploit additional information - is the list of first instances of variable names sorted ? if it is, you only have to store the lexicographically maximal variable name encountered so far (`vmax`) starting with `null` and compare list elements against it as they come. if the tested element `vcur` is less or equal than `vmax`, you have already seen the variable name before, otherwise increment a counter, associate `vcur` with it and set `vmax` to `vcur`.

Comment: i must clarify -- if there are 'n' items in the list, there are 'n' hash lookups. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: still you have `O(1)` per hash lookup. and you won't come off with less than `n` operations in total because you have to check each variable name (unless you have extra information allowing you to skip elements or terminating prematurely).